# Can this dyadic method be refactored to a monadic method naturally

Tags: parameters, dependency-injection, refactoring, reduce

I am trying to write my own neural network framework as an exercise. To keep it simple I will present a toy example of a neuron.

We have a Neuron class

```
class Neuron:
   def __init__(self,representation,trainer):
      # initialize   

   def compute(self,input):
      # compute output

   def train(self,dataset):
      self.representation = self.trainer(self.representation,dataset)

   def getRepresentation(self):
      return self.representation
```

The neuronRepresentation class is a simple wrapper data object

```
class NeuronRepresentation:
   def __init__(self,weights,bias,activation):
      #initialize
```

But the train method is long and complex plus we would like to be able to use different trainers (strategies).

```
 class SomeNeuronTrainer:
    def _init__(self):
       #initialize

    def train(self,representation,dataset)
       #train and return representation
```

So basically by using dependency injection we create the model as followed

```
representation = NeuronRepresentation([1,1,1],1,SigmoidActivation()) 
trainer = SomeNeuronTrainer()
model = Neuron(representation,trainer)

model.compute(someinput)
model.train(somedataset)
model.compute(someinput)
```

---

As you can see, the train method of trainer has 2 inputs

A possible solution would be to inject the representation in the constructor of the trainer as well so Neuron class delegates and then requests the result.

```
class Neuron
   ...
   def train(self,dataset)
      self.trainer.train(dataset)
      self.representation = self.trainer.getRepresentation()  
   ...

trainer = SomeNeuronTrainer(representation)
model = Neuron(representation,trainer)
```

This however does not seem right to me and is counterintuitive. When we want to swap trainers at runtime we would need to do this

```
model.changeTrainer(SomeOtherTrainer(model.getRepresentation))
```

instead of

```
model.changeTrainer(SomeOtherTrainer())
```

edit: 
We could also let the trainer have some method setRepresentation(representation) and let the Neuron set it in its own initialization or when we change trainers. But this also means that the Trainer object cannot be used readily after initialization, only after the representation is set and my belief prohibits me from creating such objects.
And to solve this issue we would need to do even something sillier and inject a builder.

```
def changeTrainer(self,trainerBuilder)
   self.trainer = trainerBuilder.build(representation)

model.changeTrainer(SomeTrainerBuilder())
```

All of this just to remove a parameter. So yes it is possible, but my question is whether or not it is possible in a way that would seem natural.